# One of the provided arguments is not acceptable creating folder using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph Library for PHP (microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) to save documents in Onedrive for Business.

I am having issues to create items (folders or upload files) using Microsoft Graph API, for instance, when I am creating folders I am getting:

```
"Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/MYDRIVEID/items/MYPARENTFOLDERID/children` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": { "code": "invalidRequest", "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.", "innerError": { "request-id": "bec1d260-3efd-4417-ba80-96ec37078df6", "date": "2018-07-20T16:48:34" } } } "
```

POST

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/MYDRIVEID/items/MYPARENTFOLDERID/children

body:

```
{"name":"Project1","folder":{}}
```

This is the code I am executing:

```
$graph->createRequest("POST","/drives/$driveId/items/$itemId/children")- 
>attachBody($body)->setReturnType(Model\DriveItem::class)->execute();
```

My guess is that the API is expecting something different than I am sending, I have tried to change the body, for instance:

```
{"name":"Project1","folder":{"childCount":0}}
{"name":"Project1","folder":{},"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"rename"} 
{"name":"Project1","folder":{"childCount":0},"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"rename"}
```

but I am still getting the same error.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the app registration and registered it again in azure portal. Create folder operation is working as expected.