# PATCH update on Sharepoint - One of the provided arguments is not acceptable

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MSGraph API in Javascript to read and update Sharepoint lists, I am successfully retrieving data, but every time I try to update a value using a PATCH call, I get:

[image]

The URL is:
[image]

Here is the request headers/payload/response headers:
[image]

The strange thing is when I try this on MS Graph Explorer it works, and the request headers and payload are identical.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is a snapshot of the code I am using:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the Payload that you have used in javascript?

Comment: The payload is just one field:   {"POD":244}.

Comment: Try putting Doublequotes(") for 244 and see if it works.

Comment: Still doesn't work with quotes around the number. The column is configured as Number in the Sharepoint list, and it works without the quotes in MSGraph Explorer.

Comment: Please share the code of the Javascript that sends the payload with the call.

Comment: Try using the below code `const fieldValueSet = {POD:244};

let res = await client.api('/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/lists/ff0ff013-ba77-49ce-8348-6dbed70bf212/items/1/fields')
 .update(fieldValueSet);`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Still didn't work, I have added a screenshot of the code to the original post

Comment: Use get request on the same call and see what are the fields there for that item and then troubleshoot. Also open the sharepoint list in UI and cross check if everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did a get request using the same url and it pulled the data fine, and shows the "POD" column. From what I can see everything is ok in the UI as well.

Comment: According to this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450929/one-of-the-provided-arguments-is-not-acceptable-creating-folder-using-microsoft) you can try deleting the app registration and registered it again in azure portal. See if it can help.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the resolution to this issue was to create a new app registration in azure portal, it was set up with the same permissions as the one that didn't work, so not sure how it fixed it, but it did.